# add bidder as a schema field in prebid floors module?

Tags: prebid.js, prebid

I want to add "bidder" as a schema field in the prebid floor module and set a value for each bidder such as:
'video|bidder1': 1.00,
'video|bidder2': 0.60,
'video|bidder3': 0.30

would anyone have any clue how to do this, there is a additionalSchemaFields:  but i dont know how to use that?